# Elements of type 'Receivers' are not supported at the 'Site' scope. This feature could not be installed

Tags: 2007, list, event-handlers

I created a event receiver for survey list types "102" why I can't scope it as anything other then "Web" scoped. If its Microsoft's restriction only option I got is to add it to template and then save template and use it or using code activate it to every single web.

I am pretty sure I created a site collection based feature for a list before but didn't received this error.

Also Is there anyway I can attach any event handler to "Respond to this Survey" button in survey list as ItemAdding isn't helping.

Comment: I think that is the CKSDEV template for it that allows you to go beyond web scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007 Event Receivers are "Web Scoped" only, see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454835%28v=office.12%29.aspx) documentation,

and answer to your second question it is not possible with event receiver - check out the available event receiver - [List Evenets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx) & [Item Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks but what could be the solution as I figured out myself that there's Microsoft restriction on scope of feature and I am not sure why you given me link to types of item events ? :S

Comment: You cant scope it to 'Site' so basically simple OOB way does not exists, as you have already figured out "using code activate it to every single web" - you can activate the feature with the help of powershell script or C# console application, that's not a huge task, will take your 15 mins time and I gave you item events link as you yourself mentioned "ItemAdding isn't helping", from the link you can understand ItemAdding is not supposed to help, better hear it from official doc than me

Comment: I understand that but whats the solution your proposing your answer :S

Comment: I never proposed a solution, I just confirmed Event Receivers are "Web Scoped" only, so that you dont waste your time on making it site scoped, i thought proposing custom code solution would be redundant as you already figured that out, and your second requirement is not achievable - you definitely can not attach event handler to 'Respond to this survey', so what solution do you expect me to propose?